# JS: How to fix "Expected ')' to match '(' from line 4 and instead saw '='." JSLint error

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have written the following function:

```
function MyTest(element, no, start=0) {
    this.no = no;
    this.element = element;
    this.currentSlide = start;

    self.start();
}
```

JSLint complains:

> Expected ')' to match '(' from line 4 and instead saw '='.

What is wrong with this? Is it the default value I've set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have default values for arguments (yet; it [will in the next version](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:parameter_default_values), and as [Boldewyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113195/boldewyn) points out in a comment, Firefox's engine is already there), so the `=0` after `start` is invalid in JavaScript. Remove it to remove the error.

To set defaults values for arguments, you have several options.

1. Test the argument for the value `undefined`:

   ```
   if (typeof start === "undefined") {
       start = 0;
   }
   ```

   Note that that does not distinguish between `start` being left off entirely, and being given as `undefined`.
2. Use `arguments.length`:

   ```
   if (arguments.length < 3) {
       start = 0;
   }
   ```

   Note, though, that on some engines using `arguments` markedly slows down the function, though this isn't nearly the problem it was, and of course it doesn't matter except for **very few** functions that get called a *lot*.
3. Use JavaScript's [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) depending on what the argument in question is for. In your case, for instance, where you want the value to be `0` by default, you could do this:

   ```
   start = start || 0;
   ```

   That works because if the caller provides a "truthy" value, `start || 0` will evaluate to the value given (e.g., `27 || 0` is `27`); if the caller provides any **falsey** value, `start || 0` will evaluate to `0`. The "falsey" values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course `false`. "Truthy" values are all values that aren't "falsey".

Comment: Actually, Firefox 15 and above allow default values, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters . That illustrates the importance of JS[HL]int before pushing things in production.

Comment: @Boldewyn: Yes, but in normal conversation, "JavaScript" means ECMAScript (even though of course "JavaScript" is a Mozilla trademark for *their* implementation of ECMAScript). ECMAScript doesn't have default values (yet; it will in the next version, I added a link), so you can't use them unless you *know* you're only going to be working with a subset of engines that already support them.

Comment: @Boldewyn Thanks, thats great to know, because the function throws an error in Safari but not Firefox!

Comment: Thanks for the correction! It's especially interesting, when you use Traceur or Typescript as thin wrapper around your JS, http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-default-argument.html, since both (and many others) already can handle that syntax. So you can use the syntax today, as long as you add a “compile” step for browsers.

Comment: @Boldewyn: Indeed yes! :-) As long as it's something Traceur or similar (can) provide.