# jshint javascript error - Expected ')' to match '{' from line n and instead saw 'response'. (E020)

Tags: javascript, nodes, jshint, fixer.io

I am following the SPA tutorial at [Build a JavaScript Single Page App Without a Framework](https://www.sitepoint.com/single-page-app-without-framework/)

I have the below code in my server.js file, and it is giving an error:

```
const get = async (url) => {
  const response = await api.get(url);
  const { data } = response;
  if (data.success) {
    return data;
  }
  throw new Error(data.error.type);
};
```

the error I am getting is:

> [jshint] "Expected ')' to match '{' from line 15 and instead saw 'response'. (E020)

another error I am getting (on the same line) is:

> [jshint] "Expected an identifier and instead saw '='. (E030)

at the top of the file I have tried:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
```

and

```
"ecmaVersion: 8";
```

so what is wrong here? I have searched for the error and found [SO: JS: How to fix “Expected ')' to match '(' from line 4 and instead saw '='.” JSLint error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490718/js-how-to-fix-expected-to-match-from-line-4-and-instead-saw-jsli)

which didn't really help...

so what can I do in my project, or in that code to resolve this?

Comment: looks like async and awaut not supported .. U need a pollyfil or something

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I have installed polyfill with `npm install polyfill` - but no luck...do I need to require it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below to workplace SETTINGsettings

```
{
  "jshint.options": {
    "esversion": 6
  }
}
```